# XRDP with Finnish keyboard?

Tags: configuration, vnc, rdp, xrdp

How I can get Finnish keyboard layout to work with XRDP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As root:

```
cd /etc/xrdp
cp km-041d.ini km-040b.ini
```

This copies Swedish keyboard layout to Finnish keyboard layout.

Now run in your actual X session (**not xrdp**):

```
setxkbmap -layout fi
```

Then connect to this machine via Windows RDP client and Finnish keyboard layout works.

Comment: I couldn't use that setxkbmap command even after copying the file, but restarting xrdp did the trick.